# Apply jquery css to contenteditable text selection

Tags: jquery, css, selection, contenteditable

Can i apply css to selected text in a contenteditable div instead of using execcommand. For exmaple i would like to use jquery to apply css to a selected range such as `$(savedRange).css({'color':'red'});` But that does work. Can this be done.

I already have the saveselection and restoreselection functions working where i can save and restore selected text. The variable savedRange is what contains the saved text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How can I use jQuery to apply css to savedRange text selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891338/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-apply-css-to-savedrange-text-selection/4928144#4928144)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap the selected text with a inline element (such as a span) and then style that element. You can try the [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function. It would be hard to say for sure without having an example.

```
$(savedRange).wrap('<span />').css({'color':'red'});
```

Comment: This doesn't work on savedRanges. I will try to post a the code on jsfiddle so you can see what i mean.