# How can I use jQuery to apply css to savedRange text selection?

Tags: jquery, css, selection, range

Is it possible to apply css or wrap tags around savedRange text selection. I'm using jquery.

this doesn't work:

```
$(savedRange).css(...);
$(savedRange).wrap(...);
```

Comment: When you make a text selection, carets gets placed on both sides of the selection to reference where the selection begins and where it ends. This information is saved in savedRange variable to later reference what was selected.

Answer (score 1):

If by "savedRange" you mean something like this:

```
selection = window.getSelection()
savedRange = selection.getRangeAt(0)
```

Then you will have to create a wrapper for the range first, like so:

```
wrapper = document.createElement('span')
savedRange.surroundContents(wrapper)
selection.selectAllChildren(wrapper)
```

You can then apply style:

```
$(wrapper).css(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work around selected text but this would put an HTML tag with some style in it around another HTML element.

```
$(savedRange).wrap('<span style="color:red" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
var tag = range.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement;

$(tag).css({'color':'red'});
// you can add css again using jquery
```

hope can help .